# Resize coulmn width of MSFlexGrid according to the size of grid VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a function which automatically resize every control according to the screen size. I tried to resize the MSFlexgrid its working but problem is columns are not resizing according automatically with it is there any function so that columns width automatically resized with it?

Comment: Sort of bizarre to scale based on screen size, since it takes too much control away from the user.  Instead scale to fit the Form, and then consider setting the initial Form size based on the screen size.  Nobody wants applications that insist on full-screening, this isn't iOS or something.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no built in auto-column scaling for MSFlexGrid. You'll have to write one yourself.

Thankfully it's fairly straightforward, although don't forget to allow for scroll bars.